# Duplicate insert when ajaxvalidation is true

Tags: yii

Im having this weird problem that causes my model to double insert into the database when ajaxvalidation is on for my form. I dont understand why this happens, but this keeps on conflicting with my custom validation and I cannot move on. Can someone enlighten me on the problem.

Model:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('category, ppmp_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('category','required'),
        array('q1, q2, q3, q4', 'numerical'),
        array('category', 'myTestUniqueMethod'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('item_id, category, q1, q2, q3, q4, ppmp_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

public function myTestUniqueMethod($attribute,$params)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM ppmp_item 
            WHERE ppmp_id='.$this->ppmp_id.'and category='.$this->category;

        $unique = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryRow();

    if ($unique)
    {
            $this->addError('category', "Category already added to PPMP");
    }

}
```

View:

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'ppmp-item-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
 )); ?>


<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'category'); ?>
    <?php 

        $data=PhilgepsCategory::model()->findAll();
        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','class_name');
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category',$data,array('options' => array('1'=>array('selected'=>true)))); 

    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'category'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'q1'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'q1'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'q1'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'q2'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'q2'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'q2'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'q3'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'q3'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'q3'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'q4'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'q4'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'q4'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate($ppmp,$bal)
{
    $model=new PpmpItem;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['PpmpItem']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['PpmpItem'];
        $model->ppmp_id = $ppmp;
        $valid=$model->validate();
        if($valid) 
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('ppmp/view','id'=>$ppmp));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'ppmp'=>$ppmp,
        'bal'=>$bal,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Also you have another problems in your programming, at the validation function, don concatenate the value of variables, just use parameters like this:


public function myTestUniqueMethod($attribute,$params)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM ppmp_item 
            WHERE ppmp_id=:ppmp_id and category=:category'; Then use  $unique = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->->bindParam(":ppmp_id",$this->ppmp_id,PDO::PARAM_STR)->bindParam(":category",$this->category,PDO::PARAM_STR)->queryRow();

Comment: Also, move the following code to the controller: $data=PhilgepsCategory::model()->findAll(); and pass it to the view, because the view shouldn't access the data. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you shouldn't execute **save()** method when validating, because it will save when doing the ajax validation and when sending the data trough the form, so, you should do something like this:

```
...
...
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='ppmp-item-form')
{
    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
    Yii::app()->end();
}

$valid=$model->validate();
     if($valid) 
        if($model->save())
...
...
```

This is the same that **gii** uses to validate using ajax.

Comment: Oh. I thought $valid would handle that one. Hence if not valid, then the model would automatically not save.